# how to use fields property of query_string to be and logically using elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, field, query-string

in `query_string` of `elasticsearch` there is a `fields` property.. that limits the search through specified fields.. it seems that by default running the `query_string` query against multiple fields is to expand each query term to an OR clause like this:

```
field1:query_term **OR** field2:query_term | ...
```

here is my question: if I want my fields go like this:

```
field1:query_term **AND** field2:query_term | ...
```

how to write my query if I want to logically `and` my fields together?

in my search its better to not to use `phrase_match` because there is functions on my search that let user choose how to search, **exact** or see **all words** in document with slops or see **one_or_more** words in result fields... right now this is OK when user choose **one_or_more**

I wish I was clear in explaining my problem.. if isn't it, let me know!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the setting `"default_operator": "AND"` to your query_string query (the default setting is `OR`):

```
POST /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "field1:query_term field2:query_term",
            "default_operator": "AND"                         <--- add this
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response @Val, I used "default_operator" like this but it didn't work.. it is my query :    
    ` "query_string" => array:5 [
            "query" => "sales*"
            "analyze_wildcard" => true
            "default_operator" => "AND"
            "boost" => 1
            "fields" => ["job_title", "education_title"]
`

Comment: but here for my search in only my fields.. it consider **OR**  between fields, not **AND**

Comment: It is different than the query you showed in your question where you had both fields in the query part. What if you try `job_title:sales* education_title:sales*` in the query part?

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot @Val.. so if I want to use like fields : ["job_title", "company_name"], there is no way to get the same results?

Comment: When using the `fields`, the query is automatically translated to an OR query as can be seen [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_multi_field)